# From_iso8601_timestamp in metabase

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, etl, amazon-athena, metabase

I have a table in athena with a string column in iso8601 format: 2023-07-10T20:53:32+0000

I want to be able to create query filters based on the date in metabase, tried to convert the string to date with "Cast to a specific data type" option, but it doesn't work since all it does is add a cast(x to timestamp), which presto doesn't know how to convert. Adding an additional function: cast(from_iso8601_timestamp(x) as timestamp) does work, when I manually alter the query.

I want to be able to do so automatically - Do anyone know if there's support for this presto function?
Can I do a manual mapping to the column some way so it will always be converted as above?